# Spacing/padding from table border and narrower rows

Tags: css, html

How do I add spacing/padding/margin from the table border?

I would want a narrower spacing between the table rows and more spacing/padding from the table border itself like:

```
<table /*inner margin/padding = 50px */>
<tr /* margin = 2px */><td>Hello</td></tr>
<tr /* margin = 2px */><td>Hello</td></tr>
<tr /* margin = 2px */><td>Hello</td></tr>
</table>
```

When I do:

```
 table border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 10px;
```

The whole rows and the padding from the border increases. I want the padding between rows much narrower than the padding from the table borders. In other words I would want the outer padding increase, not the inner rows padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Family</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@doe.com</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- So on -->
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
  padding: 48px;              /* 48 + 2 = 50px */
  border-collapse: separate;  /*      |        */
  border-spacing: 2px;  /* <-----------        */
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You could use [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property to specify the distance between the borders of adjacent cells, and [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) property to create space between borders of the table and its content.

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/uZux/2/edit)**